# Push instruction in assembly(intel 8086)

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to chose the right implement for calling a function foo than written in c. foo gets 1 arguments 0x100fa500.

the first answer is:

```
sub esp,2
mov word[esp],0xa500
sub esp,2
mov word[esp] , 0x100f
call foo
add esp 4
```

and the second:

```
 sub esp,2
 mov word[esp],0x100f
 sub esp,2
 mov word[esp] , 0xa500
 call foo
```

why the second is true? I think the first implement the right push parameter and then call

Comment: Tag as homework perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the missing `add esp, 4` at the end, the second version is correct, as the Intel architecture is little-endian. This means that a DWORD is stored in memory with its least significant BYTE or WORD occupying the lower memory address. In your case, `0xA500` is the least significant WORD of the DWORD, and the second version correctly places it in the lower 2-bytes of a 4-byte area of the stack.

Comment: but isn't the stack start from the high address?
i mean, if I will execute the first code, i will get:
10 in the lowest address of the stack  and 00 in the highest. i will get if i do: push 0x100fa500. Am i right?
and this is also what

Comment: @user1462787: everything you are saying is consistent with a big-endian architecture, which is not the case here. The fact that you are trying to put 10 in the lowest address of the stack is already wrong. In fact, the first code will put 0F in the lowest address of the stack - you are in fact making the same mistake twice (once for the byte order within a DWORD, related to what the question requires, and once for the byte order within a WORD, related to how a `mov` instruction operates.)

Comment: @user1462787: Perhaps your confusion is related to the fact that the stack grows downwards. In this sense, the stack is 'backwards', but individual data items within the stack are stored in their normal order, otherwise you wouldn't be able to access them correctly with standard DWORD- and WORD-sized `mov`s.

Comment: i think i understand now.
i know the stack grows downwards.
so, in the second code, 100f is in the address 1000 for example, and a500 is in the address 984. so when the function get pop the argument, because of the the little endian, it will be 100f9500. Am i right?
but, this is differnt from mov this to eax for example. because when i do mov eax, [esp+2] i will get something else: 9500100f.

Comment: @user1462787: `mov` and `pop` do not behave differently in that way - `mov` will also give you 0x100FA500 in `eax`, since 00 is in the first (lowest address) byte in memory, A5 in the next highest, then 0F, then 10 in the last (highest address) byte in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the calling convention but for "cdecl" it is up to the caller to clean up the stack. Which means it is your first answer that is correct because it does "add esp,4". However just like ndkrempel notice in his answer, the parameter should be passed as little-endian like in the second answer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: I think the caller stack clean-up or not is just a typo in the question. Notice the order of the `mov`s differs - I think that's the main thrust of the question.

Comment: @ndkrempel: I think you are right. I've edited my answer. And this is indeed probably a homework question :-)